# What is the range of high poly with current cpu and gpus

Tags: xna, directx, unity-game-engine, game-engine

In current time with current cpu and gpu which are available in market. Which game model is defined as  high poly ? for example , in a sample game , is it good to have models with minimum 24000 triangles ?
I Know there some models that they have no need to more polygons . but how much poly will affect the cpu performance ? I have supposed there is face culling , so many of faces won't be rendered.

In other words , What is the average of triangles in a eye-catching game model ?

Comment: I don't believe this question is actually answerable as "it depends". You may find this a good read, however: http://www.rsart.co.uk/2007/08/27/yes-but-how-many-polygons/ Specifically, from the link, *"the number of polygons used don’t matter if they are not used well"*

Comment: great idea, the number of polygons used don’t matter if they are not used well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [CGSociety](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-295589.html):

> In film, important character models, and objects like ships, or gollum
>   that have to hold up to very close shots are in the high millions, 60
>   is not uncommon. Its all relative to what context the object is being
>   used in.
>
> ---
>
> My idea is that as long as something is working properly, efficiently
>   and is renderable in the given time, it's ok. I don't think there's
>   really some sort of watershed number.
>
> ---
>
> 30,000 = high
>
> 20,000 = up there
>
> under 15,000 = okay
>
> 6,000 = nice
>
> greatly depends on your pipe. if you're setup is slow at 3,000, then
>   you'd need to scale down for efficiency.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_poly#Low_poly_as_a_relative_term) says about the same thing for the opposite, a low poly model:

> There is no defined threshold for a mesh to be low poly; low poly is
>   always a relative term and depends on (amongst other factors):
>   -The time the meshes were designed and for what hardware
>   -The detail required in the final mesh
>   -The shape and properties of the object in question
>
> As computing power inevitably increases, the number of polygons that
>   can be used increases too.

[The link Dash provided](http://www.rsart.co.uk/2007/08/27/yes-but-how-many-polygons/) was a great recourse also in finding out polygons in a game. It seems the average game from 2007-2008 has anywhere from 10000-25000 polygons per character.

> GTA IV, Xbox 360/PS3, 2008 Story Characters – 8-10,000 polygons with
>   multiple 256×256/512×512 diffuse, specular and normal maps
>
> Lost planet, X360/PC, 2007 Wayne – 12392 polygons (but finally 17765
>   polygons for compatibility with motion blur effect)
>
> Uncharted: Drake’s Fortune, PS3, 2007 Main characters – ~20,000-30,000
>   polygons

So, the answer is, there is no REAL answer to this question! It ALL depends on factors of how you use your game, the environment it is used in, the system hardware you are planning on using, etc. The terms "Low poly" and "High poly" are all relative to these and other factors. Basically, if it has enough polygons to suit YOUR needs with a high definition standard and still meets efficiency needs, then you are good.